# how to send value from thymyleaf to controller which is not used in view

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I am trying to send some value from view to controller however this value is not used in view.

View:

```
<form th:action="@{/changePassword}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Old Password</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:name="oldPassword">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>New Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" th:name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" >
    </div>

    <button type="submit" onclick="savePass()">Change Password</button>
</form>
```

and method in controller

```
@PostMapping("/changePassword")
    public String updatePassword(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userService.changeUserPassword(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        return "display";
    }
```

and simple model with `id`, `username`, `password`, `oldPassword` and `enable` fields.

I know I can get logged user in view by `[[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]` but how can I put it into model and send to controller. With actual code during debugging I can see that `password` and `oldPassword` are set but `username = null`.

I could add:

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
       <label>Username</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" th:name="username">
</div>
```

but I don't want user to type his username, I know who is logged and who wants to change password.

Comment: `<input type="hidden"... />` ?

Comment: @xerx593, tricky one but how does it help? Instead of `username = null` I will have `username = ""`

Comment: ...who/how GETs the view?;) ..should set! ..and even why not `${httpServletRequest.remoteUser}`?

Comment: @xerx593 got a problem with sending this as `username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to send the user from the view to the controller. Just use `@AuthenticationPrincipal` in your controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/changePassword")
    public String updatePassword(@AuthenticationPrincipal MySecurityUser securityUser, 
                                 @ModelAttribute("user") User user, 
                                 Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userService.changeUserPassword(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        return "display";
    }
```

The actual class (`MySecurityUser` in the example) to use will depend on how exactly you have set up your security. If you don't know it, type it to `Object` and print out the class name or use a debugger to see the actual class name that is used.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/mvc.html#mvc-authentication-principal for more info.

Comment: I also found: `String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();` and now it's working